# Camera App doesn't dismiss when "Not enough available storage..." on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, camera

I have an app which let's you take a picture with the iphone camera.
Everything works like a charm but when testing on a new device which happened not to have enough storage available, the camera app didn't dismiss.

So basically I open the image picker with source camera, I get a popup that says "There is not enough available storage to take a photo..." and then when I press OK, I am at the Camera app, with the shutter closed, and both the "take photo" and "cancel" buttons grayed out.
From this point on the only thing I can do is to kill the app as there is no way to leave this screen.

In my code I call the camera with something like:

```
UIImagePickerController * photoPicker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
photoPicker.delegate = self;
photoPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:photoPicker.sourceType]) {
    [self presentModalViewController:photoPicker animated:YES];
}
```

The object which call this is of course a UIImagePickerControllerDelegate and I implement both delegate methods (both respond correctly to success and cancel events):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker;
```

This "no space available" behaviour doesn't fall on any of the delegate methods, so I am unable to programatically dismiss the camera app.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**

When trying to run the app in the simulator where the Camera is not available I noticed the App crashing because that source was unavailable. I found out that simply assigning an unavailable sourceType to the photoPicker, even before calling the controller, would crash the app, so I changed the code to the following:

```
UIImagePickerController * photoPicker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
photoPicker.delegate = self;
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    photoPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
}else{
    return;
}
[self presentModalViewController:photoPicker animated:YES];
```

This still doesn't fix my problem, but it's an interesting finding.

Comment: try `isSourceTypeAvailable` before presenting the Picker. Maybe apple thought of this case.

Comment: I actually already have `isSourceTypeAvailable` in my code as a condition for presenting the photoPicker, I just stripped it to show a simpler snippet. Thanks for the contribution nonetheless! I'll edit the original post with that.

Comment: Actually I just found out that checking `isSourceTypeAvailable` before presenting photoPicker is not a good place to do so, as if the source is not available, it crashes right at the atribution of `.sourceType`. This still didn't help my problem. I'll update my original post though to reflect this finding.

Comment: Im facing the same issue with my app. Im curious to know how you dealt with the situation.

Comment: Truth is, I haven't. I didn't find any way to deal with the situation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with camera, but the rest of the application: camera has trickered `didReceiveMemoryWarning`and thus "killed" the view, where you were trying to return to. It's just not there any more.

The fix is to implement UIViewController's viewDidLoad, viewDidUnload, viewWillDisappear, viewWillAppear etc. and make sure your app can handle out of memory situation caused by Camera and initialize everything needed, when Camera disappears.

Comment: I implemented all of that but with no success. The error isn't related to lack of memory, it's lack of storage. So when I open the Camera, I do get `viewDidDisappear` called as one would expect since the Camera controller replaces the current one, but it doesn't go into `viewDidUnload` or even `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. Thanks for trying to help!